# build file with one game and two game can access it

Tags: c#, file, unity-game-engine

i use BinaryFormatter with AES to store my game data

i want to create a binary file in android in game it easy

it can be placed like this place

```
application.persistentdatapath
```

but i want to place it somewhere to another game i create can access it and read data from it how can i do that and where i must place my file to both game can access it and read/write it

```
some where like root/data/data
```

address in android and if you know also in IOS

Comment: Someone can correct me if I am wrong, but I'm pretty sure mobile apps are isolated on the device. You'd have to store the data on an external server I would think.

Comment: @mxmissile yeah i think like this too but some apps save data like under emulated /0 and i want to know how they do it or which path i must give to formatter to save there and after it i think its possible to read from there via another app/game