# get data from a server via unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, server

I'm using unity and I want to receive last build number stored in a online data base

How I can receive data I searched and find I must use www to do it but I don't know how.

I use to create a WWWForm and add field and add my data to it and then send it to post data to server

Is it possible receive data like wwwform does on send?

Any document about send/receive data via unity will be good also

Comment: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/11021/how-can-i-send-and-receive-data-to-and-from-a-url.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8951489/unity-get-post-wrapper

Comment: @Umair M many thanks is there more detailed version?

Comment: Try to use it first and let me know if there is a problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve data *send/receive* functionality thourgh three things in (C# + Unity). Its [Co-routine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html), [WWW](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html), [WWWForm](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWWForm.html)

Demo of both given below:

**For Get Request:**

```
 using UnityEngine;

 public class GetRequestDEmo : MonoBehaviour {

     void Start () {
         string url = "http://exampleWeb.com/myServerScript.php?var1=value2&amp;var2=value2";
         WWW www = new WWW(url);
         StartCoroutine(WaitForRequest(www));
     }

     IEnumerator WaitForRequest(WWW www)
     {
         yield return www;

         // check for errors
         if (www.error == null)
         {
             Debug.Log("WWW Result!: " + www.text);// contains all the data sent from the server
         } else {
             Debug.Log("WWW Error: "+ www.error);
         }    
     }
 }
```

**For Post Request:**

```
public class PostRequestDemo : MonoBehaviour {

     void Start () {

         string url = "http://exampleWeb.com/myServerscript.php";

         WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
         form.AddField("var1", "value1");
         form.AddField("var2", "value2");
         WWW www = new WWW(url, form);

         StartCoroutine(WaitForRequest(www));
     }

     IEnumerator WaitForRequest(WWW www)
     {
         yield return www

         // check for errors
         if (www.error == null)
         {
             Debug.Log("WWW Ok!: " + www.text);// contains all the data sent from the server
         } else {
             Debug.Log("WWW Error: "+ www.error);
         }    
     }    
 }
```

**If you want server side code (in PHP) also then, I will recommend you [this Unity Wiki code](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=Server_Side_Highscores).** Or you can also watch [this Video.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3pcvJYJinn4)

Comment: i not watch all of video but i think it's what i want thanks a lot :) any help for this also? :D http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38722483/build-file-with-one-game-and-two-game-can-access-it

Answer (score 1):

i can recommend your another method so miradb is simply json based database server and supported unity engine you can try this.

**Mira-DB install *(nodejs)***

[www.npmjs.com/package/mira-db](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mira-db)

**Unity Example project**

[https://github.com/Nodeclient](https://github.com/Nodeclient/Mira-DB/tree/master/CLIENT%20EXAMPLE/Express%20Server%20clients/Example%20Client%20(UNITY5%20GAME%20ENGINE))